# ionic Framework 3 firebase google authentication

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication, ionic3

I have been having some problems with Firebase authentication and am looking for some help.

Basically, for my Google+ login, I am able to open up an in-app browser and select the profile I wish to login into. However, it seems like the authentication stops there as I am led back to my original page. I have used `*ngIf` to change the layout of the login page when I return but the changes are not shown. Anyone have any idea?

My code for the HTML is as below:

```
<button block ion-button (click)="login('facebook')" *ngIf = "!provider.loggedin" item-left>
  <ion-icon name="logo-facebook"></ion-icon> &nbsp; &nbsp; Login With Facebook
</button>
<button block ion-button (click)="login('google')" *ngIf = "!provider.loggedin" item-left>
  <ion-icon name="logo-googleplus"></ion-icon> &nbsp; &nbsp; Login With Google
</button>
<ion-card *ngIf = "provider.loggedin">
  <img src="{{ provider.profilePicture }}"/>
  <ion-card-content>
    <ion-card-title>
      {{ provider.name }}
      </ion-card-title>
    <p style = "text-align: center">
      {{ provider.email }}
    </p>
  </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>

<button block ion-button (click)="FinalLogin()" *ngIf = "provider.loggedin" item-left>Please Enter!!</button>
<button block ion-button (click)="logout()" *ngIf = "provider.loggedin" item-left>Logout</button>
```

The code for `home.ts` is as follows:

```
login(provider){
  let signInProvider = null;
  console.log("Help")
  switch(provider){
    case "facebook":
    signInProvider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider()
    console.log("Help2")
    break;

    case "google":
    signInProvider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()
    console.log("helping me")
    break;

  } 

  console.log("help3")

  this.fire.auth.signInWithRedirect(signInProvider)
  .then ( () => {
    console.log("Help4")     
      this.fire.auth.getRedirectResult().then( res => {         

      console.log(res)
      console.log('from -Google--')

      this.provider.loggedin = true;
      this.provider.name = res.user.displayName;
      this.provider.name = res.user.email;
      this.provider.profilePicture = res.user.photoURL;
      this.ref.detectChanges();
      console.log(res)

      this.navCtrl.push(LoggedinPage);

      });
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your call to `this.fire.auth.signInWithRedirect(signInProvider` might be silently failing, because you're not `catch`-ing any errors.

Try this:

```
this.fire.auth.signInWithRedirect(signInProvider)
    .then(() => { /* existing code */ })
    .catch(error => console.error(error));
```

to rule out any possibility of silent failure.  Then, address any errors that might be occurring within the sign-in process as appropriate.

Comment: Hi thanks for replying. I have tried and implemented your changes, to no avail. There are no changes indicated.

Comment: Hi thanks for replying. I have tried and implemented your changes, to no avail. There are no changes seen from the console?

Comment: Could you please update the code in your question with the change so that I can take a look?